# Load Analysis GUI tools for Linux - individual process and overall

Tags: linux, monitoring

I need to do some load analysis on a Linux server and would like a nice GUI to help me.  I don't need any fancy history, logging, or alerting.  I need more information than top, and would like it wrapped in one utility or package that is not difficul tto set up.  Something like Process Explorer on Windows:

Statistics

- Viewable for Global, individual Processes, and individual Threads
- CPU

  - Usage
  - Kernel Time, User Time
  - Context Switch Delta
  - Interrupt Delta
  - DPC Delta
  - Handles
  - Threads
  - Processes
- Memory

  - Virtual Memory
  - Working Set
  - Private
  - Page Faults
- I/O

  - Separate for Network / Disk
  - Total/Delta Read/Write
  - Open sockets, file handles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend [Observium](http://observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) if you want a pretty web-based display of system information. It covers most of the attributes you wish to track and works well in single-server installs as well as multiple system deployments. Take 20 minutes to set it up and give it a try. There's also a [live demo available](http://demo.observium.org/).

[image]

If you need realtime data in a text user interface, look at [collectl](http://collectl.sourceforge.net/).

---

Edit:

Today, I recommend [Netdata](https://my-netdata.io).
https://my-netdata.io

Answer (score 1):

You could get some useful information from utilities like dstat or sar.
Those two are usually easily installed with a package manager like apt.

The best tool I know to analyze Linux performance is [Collectd](http://www.collectd.org) but it requires you to set it up to produce rrd files and to install some apps to show graphs (like kcollectd) or some web cgi (included with collectd)

Answer (score 1):

and of course there's collectl - not related to collectd.  no set up required, just install the rpm and /etc/init.d/collectl start.  collects far more data than sar and has no external dependencies.

re rrd - be careful as it does NOT plot all the data you collect, that is if you collect it fairly frequently like collectl does, about 1 sample every 10 seconds.  Of course there are a lot of people who are happy collecting data every 5-10 minutes and while it gives a warm feeling that everything is fine, there could be a lot more going on that you're missing by not being finer grained in your monitoring.

-mark